# how the value of "number" was changed in a LUA iterator?

Tags: lua, iterator

I'm just a beginner of LUA. I don't understand why the value of the object "number" was changed in this body. Thanks in advance if you could answer me.

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount, number)--how the value of "number" was changed?
    currentNumber = number + 1
    if currentNumber<=iteratorMaxCount
    then
        return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber, number
    end
end


for i,n ,k in square,3,-1
do
    print(i,n,k)
end
```

this is the solution:

```
lua.exe iterator.lua
0   0   -1
1   1   0
2   4   1
3   9   2
```

Comment: It was not changed in the body.  The first value returned from the iterator (currentNumber) will be passed as the second argument (number) next time the iterator will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the initial call of square in a for loop, number set to the value of `currentNumber` returned from the last call.

This is a "stateless" iterator,  [Programming in Lua: 7.3 – Stateless Iterators](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html) covers this topic.

The semantics of a for loop are discussed [Programming in Lua: 7.2 – The Semantics of the Generic for](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.2.html)

With the information from those section we can know, that a for loop works as described 7.2

```lua
    do
      local _f, _s, _var = explist
      while true do
        local var_1, ... , var_n = _f(_s, _var)
        _var = var_1
        if _var == nil then break end
        block
      end
    end
```

our function `square` would be the function referenced as `_f`. after each loop we pass in the first value returned by the `square` back into it as the second arg, shown above as `_var`.